# PythonAnywhere "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded "

Tags: numpy, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to upload a bot to the server and encountered this error when installing numpy. Although before that I also installed it and everything worked then I changed the virtual environment and this error popped up.

[image]

There is still a lot of free memory, I even tried to delete everything and fill the project with a new one, but I still encounter this error.

Perhaps this is the problem exactly PythonAnywhere someone may have encountered
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes pip requires much more disk space during the installation than the size of the installed package. That's why some packages are impossible to install for free accounts on PythonAnywhere. You can use pre-installed ones. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/

Answer (score 8):

Disabling the cache worked for me

first clear the cache

```
pip3 cache purge
```

then install without caching

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I am install in my home directory. I have ~2 Terabytes available as free space, and yet, pip is struggling quite a lot to install a few simple packages. 
`3.3T  1.2T  2.1T  38% /home/shailen`

Comment: does it say 'Disk quota exceeded' ?

Answer (score 0):

So, did you check the disk quota for the virtual environment, i.e the virtual disk allocated should be enough for the work. Please check.

Comment: I added a photo of the main storage, I don't know how to view it for a particular virtual environment(if at all possible)

Comment: ok, which virtual environment you are using, please specify that and how did you create that ?

Comment: virtualenv --python=python3.8 env

Comment: ok, so now first run this command and see what all is using your space.    du -hs /tmp ~/.[!.]* ~/* | sort -h

Comment: I added a screenshot, they say the most frequent case is related to the tmp folder, but here it weighs a little